# Ways to connect Postgresql and MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, debezium

there are several ways to connect a Postgresql database to a MongoDB (e.g. using foreign data wrappers, ToroDB, Kafka-Debezium). 
What I am wondering about is, how mature are these options, and can they be used relatively safely in a production environment? Are there any known restrictions or problems (e.g. data loss, database crashing under certain circumstances, ...). How could you minimize the risk running into such things?

Any advice is very appricated :-)

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: What are your constraints, and requirements? For example, Kafka is a great option, if you're going to use the data elsewhere particularly. For a limited scope, it could be overkill.

Comment: Dear Robin, thanks for your reply! I don't have any concrete requirements. But, if so, in production, it would be stability and minimizing the risk of data loss. And that's where my question comes from: How could I compare/benchmark the mentioned options, which all depend on third-party drivers (of somehow unknown quality)?